# Why is my implementation of Equals() not called by AreEqual()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have seen many instructions ([Why does Assert.AreEqual(T obj1, Tobj2) fail with identical objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793065/why-does-assert-areequalt-obj1-tobj2-fail-with-identical-objects), [Unit Test Assert.AreEqual failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328218/unit-test-assert-areequal-failed), [Assert.AreEqual fails with the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825663/assert-areequal-fails-with-the-same-type)) to implement `Equals`/`IEqualityComparer` for my classes, if I want to check for equality based on field values rather than reference.

In an attempt to do so, I couldn't get it to work and narrowed the problem down to the following.

My class *Subject* needs to be tested. In *SubjectTestEqual*, I would expect both instances to be equal, but the result is "Assert.AreEqual failed. Also, if I debug the code, I see no calls to *Equals* nor to *GetHashCode*.

Based on the mystifying "The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T." in the [EqualityComparer.Default Property documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.EQUALITYCOMPARER%601.DEFAULT%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true), I also tried with IEquatable (uncomment code to see the effect) to no avail.

```
public class Subject : IEqualityComparer<Subject>//, IEquatable<Subject>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Subject(int name) { Id = name; }

    public bool Equals(Subject x, Subject y)
    { return (x.Id == y.Id); }

    public int GetHashCode(Subject obj)
    { return Id; }

    //public bool Equals(Subject other)
    //{ return Equals(this, other); }
}

[TestClass]
public class SubjectTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SubjectTestEqual()
    { Assert.AreEqual<Subject>(new Subject(1), new Subject(1)); }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SubjectTestSame()
    {
        Subject test = new Subject(1);
        Assert.AreEqual<Subject>(test, test);
    }
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Based on other answers, I worked out some sort of answer. See below.

Answer (score 5):

You have to override the base methods in order to call yours :

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{ ... }

public override int GetHashCode()
{ ... }
```

But you have to apply the same signatures as the `Equals` and `GetHashcode` base methods.

Comment: I just added : IEqualityComparer<Subject>, and never bothered about the signatures. I should have noticed that I wasn't warned to use override any base methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers, they helped me further on this, but none of them helped me out completely.

If I override the Equals and GetHashCode methods of object like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{ return true; }

public override int GetHashCode()
{ return 0; }
```

the methods get called and my tests will succeed. However, of course, I do not want to implement these methods for parameters of type object. Why would my class offer to compare instances with just any instance of object?

So, I modified this method to be static: `public **static** bool Equals(Subject x, Subject y)` and introduced a new test method (all test in one method for brevity):

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SubjectTestWithSubjectEquals()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Subject.Equals(new Subject(1), new Subject(1)));
        Assert.IsTrue(new Subject(1).Equals(new Subject(1)));
        Assert.IsFalse(Subject.Equals(new Subject(1), new Subject(2)));
        Assert.IsFalse(new Subject(1).Equals(new Subject(2)));
    }
```

These tests will succeed. However, I am not sure if this is a good way to proceed. For one thing, for `Assert.IsTrue((new Subject(1)) == (new Subject(1)));` to succeed, I needed to implement:

```
public static bool operator ==(Subject x, Subject y)
    { return Equals(x, y); }
```

and that reuqires also:

```
public static bool operator !=(Subject x, Subject y)
    { return !Equals(x, y); }
```

Also, going one step further, wishing to be able to compare lists of type Subject, I tried this test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SubjectTestWithCollections()
{
    var list1 = new List<Subject>() { new Subject(1), new Subject(2) };
    var list2 = new List<Subject>() { new Subject(1), new Subject(2) };
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list1, list2);
}
```

this will fail, as apparently, each item will be compared using Assert.AreEqual, rather than Subject.Equals. I have seen [issues with CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194966/mstest-collectionassert-areequivalent-failed-the-expected-collection-contains/5197536#5197536), which makes me wonder if this is mainly caused by the way Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting is implemented, or that I shouldn't try to fuss with Equals in general.

Answer (score 0):

Your TestClass violates the contract of `Object.Equals`. `Assert.AreEqual` is relying on that contract, quite reasonably.

The docs state (in the list of requirements):

x.Equals(a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic)) returns false.

Comment: What is the 'contract' of Object.Equals? The signature? Why did you choose that quote from the docs? I'm not passing any null values.

Answer (score 0):

`Assert.AreEqual` will exclusively use the `Equals` method of the first parameter that is passed in.  It has now knowledge of your `IEqualityComparer` implementation, so it will not be used.

Normally, when a class needs to compare objects for equality it will have an optional parameter of an `IEqualityComparer` that the class can use to do comparisons instead of the `Equals` method of the object itself, however `Assert.AreEqual` accepts no such parameter.  This means that to use `Assert.AreEqual` you would need to override the `Equals` method inherited from `object`, which is:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj){}
```

It makes very little sense for a type to implement `IEqualityComparer` *of it's own type*.  The idea of `IEqualityComparer` is it allows you to compare *some other type* for equality, not "yourself".

Comment: I am trying to grasp this. I am using the generic version 'public static void AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual)'. Thus, the first parameter passed in is of type Subject. Thanks for clarifying the meaning of IEqualityComparer<T>. If I understand correctly, implementing IEqualityComparer<Subject2> on Subject, would allow me to compare Subject instances to Subject2 instances.

Comment: @R.Schreurs No, it's more that an `IEqualityComparer` allows you to compare two classes when you don't have control over the definition of `Equals`, or when there might be multiple definitions.  So perhaps you want to make an `IEqualityComparer<string>` in that does a case insensitive comparison, or write an `IEqualityComparer<List<Subject>>` that compares a list based on the values in the list rather than the reference of the list, etc.